# Generating functions for $n*2^n$ & the seq a0+a1+a2+...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

1) What is the generating function of $a_n = n2^n, n\geq0$?

My answer: $f(x) = \sum a_nx^n = \sum n2^nx^n = \sum n(2x)^n$, but I have no idea where to go from here.

2) Let the sequence $s_n = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$. What is its generating function?

My answer: $f(x) = \sum a_nx^0 = \sum a_n ....$ this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We want $\sum n(2x)^n$. Note that 
$$1+2x+(2x)^2+ (2x)^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
for suitable $x$. Differentiate term by term, and you are almost there.

Comment: so we need to get to n*2^(n-1)? And then show that this is the differential of SUM 2^n = differential of 1/(1-2x) = 2/(1-2x)^3. Is that right?

Comment: For $\sum n2^n x^n=\sum n(2x)^n$, we differentiate $\frac{1}{1-2x}$, getting $\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}$. This is $\sum 2n(2x)^{n-1}$. Cancel the $2$, and multiply by $2x$ to get the right powers of $2x$.